# bundler: failed to load command: NameError

Tags: jekyll, bundle

here are my environments

```
MacOS catalina
json
jekyll -v => 4.0.0
ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580)
```

Then I tried but not it works.
what is NameError..?

```
$ bundle exec jekyll bulild --trace
```

> Configuration file: /Users/macsim/Macsim2.github.io/_config.yml
>   bundler: failed to load command: jekyll (/usr/local/bin/jekyll)
>   NameError: uninitialized constant Faraday::Error::ClientError
>   Did you mean?  Faraday::ClientError
>   ...

Please help me. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your `Gemfile` to point to an older version of `faraday`:

```
gem 'faraday', '~> 0.17'
```

The actual error is caused by `octokit` gem. But a new release will take some time.
Until then, the above workaround should suffice.